# UnetStack : How to get an automatic transmission of data between two modems 2

Tags: groovy, unetstack

I already asked a question 1 week ago about a problem that I have. I have two subnero WNC-M25MSS3 modems, my goal is to realize a 2 nodes network. I've created scripts to request data from one modem and the other can answer back. But, it is working only if I enter the script command by hand in the shell in my modems. My problem is about make this communication of data automatic, I want to launch a script automatically when the modem is powered up and I don't know how to do that.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you have new insights, please edit the original question. SO is a QnA site and no forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run your script from the `startup.groovy` script in the `scripts` folder. This is automatically run every time the modem boots up.

See the "Startup scripts" sidebar in the [UnetHandbook](https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_state_persistence.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can't run my script from the startup script, it is not working but maybe I can have some result with fshrc.groovy. However it is always the same, I can't launch my script even with saved-state.groovy.

Comment: How are you launching the script? If your script is in the `scripts` folder and can be run from the shell, you should be able to launch it from `startup.groovy` using `run 'xxx'` where `xxx.groovy` is your script name.